# I am able to select rows from a column based on one parameter, however not two?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gtfs

So I am trying to select rows with labels values between 4501 and 4524 in the column `vehicle.vehicle.id`. When I try this

```
df = df.loc[df["vehicle.vehicle.id"].between(4501,4524)]
```

I get this

```
(0,11)
```

Where there is not anything in between as indicated (0,11), same thing when broke it down

```
df = df.loc[(df["vehicle.vehicle.id"] >= 4501) & (df["vehicle.vehicle.id"] <= 4524)]
print(df.shape)

(0,11)
```

However, when I tried this, it works, why will it not take multiple parameters?? (115,11) is indicating that it is able to find 115 instances of vehicle id greater than 4501.

```
df = df.loc[df["vehicle.vehicle.id"] >=4501]
print(df.shape)

(115,11)
```

Comment: hmm, if `.between(4501,4524)` return 0 rows and `>=4501` return 115 rows, it means there are 115 values `> 4524`.

Comment: Unfortunately not understand question - if use different conditions got different ouputs, what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

*TDLR; you dont have an issue with taking in multiple parameters.*

**The Detailed / possible Explanation below:**

1. sharing the sample data like what i have done here, will be helpful in figuring out the issue. It also helps to give a much better context to the problem which u are facing.
2. like what @jezrael mentioned, it could be the case where, in your records, **you do not have any records** between the id(s) 4501 to 4524, but you have records after id 4524.
3. here is an example illustrated below based on your functions. there is nothing wrong with your query. perhaps what you are trying to find is not there.

**Code Example Illustrated below:**

```
import pandas as pd
_list = [
{'vehicle.vehicle.id' : 1, 'vehicle_name' : 'a'},
{'vehicle.vehicle.id' : 2, 'vehicle_name' : 'b'},
{'vehicle.vehicle.id' : 3, 'vehicle_name' : 'c'},
{'vehicle.vehicle.id' : 4, 'vehicle_name' : 'd'},    
]
_df = pd.DataFrame(_list)
```

[![pandas table example][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFb2V.png

```
##############
first approach
##############
_range = _df.loc[_df['vehicle.vehicle.id'].between(1,3)]
print(_range.shape) 
# outputs: (3,2) 
# means 3 rows, and 2 cols extracted
# row with the id 1,2,3 got extracted

##############
second approach
##############
_range = _df.loc[(_df['vehicle.vehicle.id'] > 1) & (_df['vehicle.vehicle.id'] < 4)]
print(_range.shape) 
# outputs: (2,2) 
# means 2 rows, and 2 cols extracted
# row with the id 2 and 3 got extracted

##############
third approach
##############
_range = _df.loc[_df['vehicle.vehicle.id'] > 3]
print(_range.shape) 
# outputs: (1,2) 
# means 1 rows, and 2 cols extracted
# row with the id 4 got extracted
```